# JGit retrieve tag name from which a new branch has been created

Tags: jgit

When creating a new branch using a tag as starting point, let's say `MyTag`,  the resulting branch is in a detached state.

Is it possibile by using the JGit API retrieve the tag name from where the new branch originated?

I would be implement a command similar to `git status` that would print:

```
HEAD detached at MyTag
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The starting point of a branch (or more generally of any ref) is not stored. Basically, a branch or tag is just a label on a certain commit-id - and of course a commit can have multiple tags or branches.

The `NameRevCommand` may help you in finding a human-readable name for a given commit.

```
RevCommit headCommit = git.commit().setMessage( "initial" ).call();
git.tag().setObjectId( headCommit ).setName( "mytag" ).setMessage( "tag on initial" ).call();
git.branchCreate().setName( "mybranch" ).setStartPoint( "refs/tags/mytag" ).call();

Map<ObjectId, String> names = git.nameRev().addPrefix( "refs/tags/" ).add( headCommit ).call();

System.out.println( names.get( headCommit.getId() ) );
```

The above snippet will return `mytag` for the `headCommit`. Note that the preference for tag names was set with `addPrefix( "refs/tags/" )`.

But beware, once a further commit is made on the new branch the relatioin to `mytag` will be lost.

BTW, a branch that is created from a tag does not *have to* result in a detached state.